# How to refactor huge lookup table in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method:

```
def assign_value
   ...
   @obj.value = find_value
end
```

and a huge lookup table:

```
def find_value
   if @var > 0 && @var <= 30
      0.4
   elsif @var > 30 && @var <= 50
      0.7
   elsif @var > 50 && @var <= 70
      1.1
   elsif @var > 70 && @var <= 100
      1.5
   elsif @var > 100 && @var <= 140
      2.10
   elsif @var > 140 && @var <= 200
      2.95
   elsif @var > 200 && @var <= 300
      4.35
   elsif @var > 300 && @var <= 400
      6.15
   elsif @var > 400 && @var <= 500
      7.85
   elsif @var > 500 && @var <= 600
      9.65
   ...

end
```

and so on for 1800 lines.

Needless to say, it's for the tax department of an unnamed country. Right now, it's written manually (all 1800 lines of it) to account the varying length of the integer ranges and decimal return values.

Without rewriting an entire country's tax code, how would I refactor this?

The ranges and values do change on a yearly basis, and we need to maintain backwards compatibility. A database table would simplify matters, but because we're dealing with a number of different countries, each with different requirements and tax codes, creating a database table isn't as straightforward as it sounds.

Comment: Create a table in DB and look it up using appropriate `where` clause

Comment: I would make a hash first: { 0..30 => 0.4, 31..50 => 0.7 } etc. That way you can remove all conditionals.

Comment: @WandMaker not a bad idea, but if the tax code changes we'd have to recreate another table with all 1800 entries. I was hoping for something a little more...algorithmic.

Comment: better save it to DB

Comment: In my view, changing database entries is preferable than changing code and pushing new release for tax code changes.

Comment: If you're downvoting this question, at least have the courtesy to explain why.

Comment: No tax payable if @var = 141?

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry typo

Comment: Most countries compute taxes from marginal tax rates that are a non-decreasing function of (adjusted) income. For the portion of income between zero and `b0` the tax rate is `r0`, for the portion between `b0` and `b1` it is `r1`, etc. These give rise to one linear function per interval, `ai + bix`, that return total tax payable if the total income `x` falls in interval `i`. If this applies to you problem you should be computing taxes from these linear functions rather than from huge tables that are similarly constructed from these functions and are provided only for the benefit of taxpayers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're absolutely right, but in this case it's a small subset of the total equation and the lookup table with varying ranges and return values with varying increments is all we have to work with.

Comment: In that case, could you work backward to compute the intervals and marginal rates from your data, and then confirm the table is generated correctly? You might be able to do that by simply running a stepwise linear regression on your data, in the hopes that it would give a perfect fit. If the table were to change you could just re-run the code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland brilliant idea. Just wrote a quick linear regression script and voila, wiped out 1600 lines. Needs a bit more testing but if I could reach over the fibreoptic cables and pin a medal on you I would.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. After you finish your work please post a comment or do an edit to explain what you did, and post a comment to me saying you've done so. btw, the medal idea wouldn't work because fibre ends a block from my house.

Comment: I meant *piecewise* linear regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MilesStanfield's answer has pretty much the same impact as yours. As said in my comment, I would use a hash to get rid of all conditions (or cases):

```
COUNTRY_TAX_RATES = {
  0..30 => 0.4,
  31..50 => 0.7,
  51..70 => 1.1
}

COUNTRY_TAX_RATES[0..30] # 0.4
COUNTRY_TAX_RATES.select { |code| code === 10 }.values.first # 0.4
```

If you don't change the codes often you could use this. If it does change frequently you might consider using another approach (for example, store in db and manage through an user interface).

UPDATE: Now I'm no longer on my mobile I want to expand this answer a little bit further. It seems you are disregarding  @Wand Maker's proposal, but I don't think you should.

Imagine you use my hash. It is convenient, without any conditionals and easy to adjust. However, as Wand Maker points out, everytime either the range or decimal changes you need a developer to update the code. This might be ok, because you only have to do it on a yearly basis, but it is not the cleanest approach.

You want accountants to be able to update the tax rates and codes, instead of developers. So you should probably create a table which contains these attributes. I'm not sure what the ranges and decimals stand for in your example, but I hope you get the idea:

```
Tax (ActiveRecord) with range_column (Give this an explicit, explanatory name. You could also use min and max range columns), code, rate and country_id

class Tax < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :range_column

  belongs_to :country
end

Country has_many :taxes
```

If you want to know the tax rate for malta (country_id: 30), with tax code 40 (whatever this might mean) you could do something like this:

```
Tax.select(:tax_rate).joins(:country).find_by(country_id: 30, range_column: 40).tax_rate # you might need a between statement instead, can't check right now if querying a serialized hash works like this
```

Now an accountant can update the ranges, decimals or any other attribute when these change (of course you have to build a CRUD for it first).

P.s. Don't mind the naming, not sure what these numbers represent. :)

Comment: I think this method is the way to go. We'd also get the option of storing the values in the database and sending it as json if the need occurs. Thanks Peter.

Comment: I've read your edit, but I've also just built a linear regression script and found an underlying pattern for a 1600 line block in the values. Now I'm torn between making accountants handcrank 1800 lines of changes every year (very fun) or writing a method to generate those values (not so fun).

I think a combination of both methods may be the order of the day. That, and gently introducing the tax formulation department to the concept of percentages.

Comment: I see, it would be great if it is linear. I currently have no idea what the details of your application are. You can automize it if you know what will happen the next year. Or if possible, you can request excel or csv files with all tax codes and rates (provided on a yearly basis) and store the content of the files in your DB. Anyway, I'm shooting in the dark here, because I have no idea what you are working with right now.

Comment: No worries mate. You've given me plenty of good ideas. I'm hardcoding the hash in code for now and generating most of it via an algorithm because we're on a deadline, but eventually we'll move to a db-stored system as you suggested. The csv upload idea seems the be the simplest and future proof way to solve this without requiring developer input. Many thanks.

Comment: I upvoted your answer for the second part, but FYI your hash solution doesn't work. It returns `nil`. Hash lookups don't work the same way as `case` expressions (as in @MilesStanfield's answer). To get `0.4` out of the above hash you'll have to use `COUNTRY_TAX_RATES[0..30]`.

Comment: Thanks for your update and yes, you are right. I was not able to test it at that time, but now I've updated my answer with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a case statement with ranges

```
case @var
when 0..30 then 0.4
when 31..50 then 0.7
when 51..70 then 1.1
...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `inc` is income and `arr` is an array of pairs `[bp, tax]`, where

- `arr[0][0] = 0`, meaning `bp` (income "breakpoint") for the first element of `arr` is zero;
- `arr[i][0] < arr[i+1][0]`, meaning breakpoints are increasing;
- tax `arr[-1][1]` is payable if `inc >= arr[-1][0]`; and
- tax `arr[i][1]` is payable if `arr[i][0] <= inc < arr[i+1][0]`, `0 <= i <= arr.size-2`.

Tax can then be computed

```
arr.find { |bp,_| inc >= bp }.last
```

since the breakpoints are increasing.